# Symfony 3 choice list with "visible" entity/document

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I have 2 documents `category` and `supplier` and a form created from `category`. I have a nested form `category` which include `supplier`.
In `supplier` I have a boolean field `visible` and I want to be able to only choose from the choice list the `supplier` set to visible true.

In my `category` form I tried :

```
....
->add('suppliers', DocumentType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
            'choice_label' => function ($category) {
                if ($category->getVisible == true)
                return $category->getName()

            },
 ....
```

But all I've got is a choice list with 10 empty fields (without name) and only 1 choice with a name (because only this choice is set to visible true).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to filter the choices themselves rather than their label.

This can be done using a custom query used as `query_builder` option:

```
->add('suppliers', DocumentType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.visible', :visible)
            ->setParameter('visible', true);
    },
    'choice_label' => function ($category) {
        return $category->getName()
    },
    // ...
))
```

Hope I correctly understood your need.

Comment: I think this is a good way to do it. But i'm using mongo, so i did: `->add('suppliers', DocumentType::class, array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Supplier',
                'query_builder' => function (DocumentRepository $dr) {
                    return $dr->createQueryBuilder('Suppliers')
                         ->field('visible')->equals('true');
                },`
But return empty choice list, i keep diggin thanks!

Comment: Be careful, you are passing a string `'true'` instead of a boolean `true`, so it's normal that you got no results. Use mongo or mysql should not make any difference in this case.

Comment: Ah i just had to remove the simple quote between 'true'. Now it works, thanks !